# subset dataframe on similar columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with multiple columns, I would like to subset the data frame using similarly named columns.
For example my data frame looks like:

```
df1<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"),px1=c(123,456,789),px2=c(111,222,333),px3=c(278,908,456),b=c(456,123,333))
> df1
  a px1 px2 px3   b
1 a 123 111 278 456
2 b 456 222 908 123
3 c 789 333 456 333
```

Now I want to create a subset of df1 where px1 or px2 or px3 has value of 456 ( In actual scenario there are lot more variables
I tried the following, but didn't work :

```
 > subset(df1,grep("px",names(df1)) %in% c(456))
 [1] a   px1 px2 px3 b  
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I couldn't figure out the missing part - can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy approach:

```
df1[as.logical(rowSums(df1[grepl("px", names(df1))] == 456)), ]

  a px1 px2 px3   b
2 b 456 222 908 123
3 c 789 333 456 333
```

If you want to take care of multiple values, e.g., `456` and `333`, you can use this approach:

```
df1[as.logical(rowSums(sapply(df1[grepl("px", names(df1))], 
                              "%in%", c(456, 333)))), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, how does the code change if I have to look for multiple values like 456,333 ?

Comment: You would change `== 456` to `%in% c(456, 333)`

Comment: @user2382845 As josilber points out, you can use `%in%` for comparison with multiple values.

Comment: I'm getting an error with %in% > df1[as.logical(rowSums(df1[grepl("px",names(df1))] %in% c(456,333))),]
Error in rowSums(df1[grepl("px", names(df1))] %in% c(456, 333)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions